# ActionCable - How to filter out any sensitive data from log in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I want to filter `sensitive` / `large` data from actioncable log. Like this:

```
AppOnlineChannel#receive({"audio_ch"=>"{filtered}"})
```

I did not find any actioncable configuration for this task.
Do someone have any idea, how can I do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe [`config.filter_parameters`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)?

Comment: @max ok, I will try and inform here. I wrote this answer according to this issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25088

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am filtering specific field from `dispatch_action` method.

#### Method 1: for all channel

- I created a `config/initializers/actioncable.rb`, and
- Override the `dispatch_action` method

**Note: Restart server after adding this code**

```rb
# config/initializers/actioncable.rb

ActionCable::Channel::Base.class_eval do
  def dispatch_action(action, data)
    # logger.info action_signature(action, data)

    # .......... filter data start ..........
    filtered_data = data
    filtered_data['audio_ch'] = '{filtered}' if filtered_data['audio_ch'].present?
    logger.info action_signature(action, filtered_data)
    # .......... ./filter data end ..........

    if method(action).arity == 1
      public_send action, data
    else
      public_send action
    end
  rescue Exception => exception
    rescue_with_handler(exception) || raise
  end
end
```

#### Method 2: for specific channel

This monkey patch works in specific channel.

```rb
# app/channels/app_online_channel.rb

class AppOnlineChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def dispatch_action(action, data)
     # logger.info action_signature(action, data)

     # .......... filter data start ..........
     filtered_data = data
     filtered_data['audio_ch'] = '{filtered}' if filtered_data['audio_ch'].present?
     logger.info action_signature(action, filtered_data)
     # .......... ./filter data end ..........

     if method(action).arity == 1
       public_send action, data
     else
       public_send action
     end
   rescue Exception => exception
     rescue_with_handler(exception) || raise
   end
```

Comment: Neither code runs for me.

Comment: @weltschmerz I am trying to reproduce the issue. I will inform you updates.

Comment: Hi @weltschmerz , I tested with your specified Rails and Ruby version. And it perfectly works. You can check this repo: https://github.com/mahfuz10/cable_in_six